# Efficient way to find if map contains any of the keys from a list/iterable

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, iteration

I need to check if a map contains any of the keys from a list, and if it does then return the first matching value. The naive approach that comes to mind is to do it in two nested loops:

```
Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<String, String>();
fields.put("a", "value a");
fields.put("z", "value z");
String[] candidates = "a|b|c|d".split("|");
for (String key : fields.keySet()){
    for (String candidate : candidates) {
        if (key.equals(candidate)){
            return fields.get(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a nicer and more efficient way, possibly one relying on the Java standard library?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Surely something like:

```
for (String candidate : candidates) {
     String result = fields.get(key);
     if (result != null) {
         return result;
     }
}
```

The above only performs *one* map lookup per candidate key. It avoids the separate test for presence plus extraction, since extracting a non-existant key will simply give you a null. Note (thanks *Slanec*) that a null value for a valid key is indistinguishable from a non-existant key for this solution.

I don't quite understand why you're performing the case conversion, btw.

Comment: This is as efficient as it can get, but it may get tricky if `null` is a permitted value in the `Map`.

Comment: Interesting... Do I understand it correctly that the idea is to only use `map.get()` once instead of `map.contains() + map.get()` because that would avoid a second lookup? That's neat!

Comment: @NimChimpsky retainAll is descructive.

Comment: @ccpizza - that's correct. Note Slanec's caveat re. null values in the map, though

Comment: @BrianAgnew: Got it! I don't worry about null's since the keys in the map are already validated for `null`.

Comment: @ccpizza As a side note, if you'll ever need the `null` values and maximize performance (hopefully after a check with a profiler), you can overcome it by inserting a dummy object instead of `null`s. That way, you can still do a single lookup and if `null` is returned, you'll know the key wasn't there. If your dummy object is returned, you'll return `null`.

Comment: @Slanec: Thanks, this is good to know. Still, I don't see why would anyone want to store `null` keys in a map. Did you encounter a real-life use case for `null` keys?

Comment: @ccpizza Actually, yes, once, I think. In an application where we didn't have explicit control over the hashmap's content as it was user's configuration and we needed to capture a case where a setting was accessed (but not changed) or was reset to default. [Anyway, there is a SO question for this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622007/why-is-it-useful-to-have-null-values-or-null-keys-in-hash-maps)

Answer (score 26):

```
for(String candidate : candidates) {
 if(fields.containsKey(candidate)) {
  return fields.get(candidate)
 }
}
```

the best way if null values are possibly in map, and if only the first detected key is required.

Answer (score 22):

In Java 8 you can have this:

```
boolean exists = Arrays.stream(candidates).anyMatch(fields::containsKey);
```

If you just want to know if any of candidates is key to the map.

If you want to know the first or any you can use:

```
Arrays.stream(candidates).filter(fields::containsKey).findAny();
```

or

```
Arrays.stream(candidates).filter(fields::containsKey).findFirst();
```

As per @Klapsa2503 answer above

Answer (score 7):

My take:

```
Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<String, String>();
fields.put("a", "value a");
fields.put("z", "value z");
String[] candidates = "a|b|c|d".split("|");
for (String candidate : candidates) {
    if (fields.containsKey(candidate)) {
        return fields.get(candidate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In Java 8 you can use this:

```
return candidates.stream()
            .filter(fields::containsKey)
            .findFirst()
            .map(fields::get)
            .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
Set<String> keySet = new HashSet<String>(fields.keySet());    
keySet.retainAll(list);
```

so `keySet` is supposed to have all keys from HashMap which are mentioned in the list

Comment: This is, I believe, the shortest way. However, it may be not the fastest one since the looping ends at the first found result, but this continues its work till the end.

Comment: @Slanec, yes it depends whether OP wants to get all keys or just first one.

Answer (score 2):

Try as

```
    List list= Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    map.put(1, 1);
    map.put(3, 3);
    Set set = new HashSet(map.keySet());
    set.retainAll(list);
    System.out.println(set);
    Object e = set.isEmpty() ? null : set.iterator().next();
    System.out.println(e);
```

output

```
[1, 3]
1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<String, String>();
fields.put("a", "value a");
fields.put("z", "value z");
String[] candidates = "a|b|c|d".split("|");
List<String> canList = Arrays.asList(candidates );
for (String key : fields.keySet()){

if (canList .contains(key)) {
return fields.get(key);
}

}
```

Comment: **Note** : canList.contains is linear in time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single loop if you assume the key of the map are already in lower case, in the same way you assume the lookup values are in lower case.